# How to see the fields of the children class if i make visible in inspector the father class?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an enum of types of obstacles, which I use to change the public instance of the obstacle father class to the specific child.

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class ObstacleDefiner : MonoBehaviour{
 public enum ObstacleType { Box, BoxRot };
 public ObstacleType type;
 private ObstacleType actualType;

 public Obstacle obstacleDefine;

 void Update()
 {
     if(actualType != type)
     {
         AdaptObstacleToType();
     }
 }

 private void AdaptObstacleToType()
 {
    obstacleDefine = GetObstacle();
    actualType = type;
 }

 Obstacle GetObstacle()
 {
    Obstacle obstacle;

    switch (type)
    {
        case ObstacleType.Box:
            obstacle = new Box(this.gameObject);
            return obstacle;

        case ObstacleType.BoxRot:
            obstacle = new BoxRot(this.gameObject);
            return obstacle;

        default:
            return obstacle = new Obstacle(this.gameObject);
     }
 }
}
```

This is the code of the main class where I define the type of obstacle

What I want to see in the inspector is not only the fields of the parent class but also those of the specific child.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Obstacle
{
  //Campos comunes a todos los obstáculos
  [HideInInspector]
  public GameObject obstacle;
  public float fallSpeed;

  //Funcionalidades especificas para cada tipo de obstáculo
  public bool hasRot;
  public bool hasSkill;

  public Obstacle(GameObject obstacle)
  {
      this.obstacle = obstacle;
  }
}
```

This is the code for the Obstacle father class who is show cause I'm declaring an obstacle variable type, but in the adapter I'm creating a new obstacle type of the specific children class.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Box : Obstacle
{

   public Box(GameObject obstacle) : base(obstacle)
   {
       //El tipo más básico de obstáculo
       hasRot = false;
       hasSkill = false;
   }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class BoxRot : Obstacle
{
  public float rotSpeed;

  public BoxRot(GameObject obstacle) : base(obstacle)
  {
      //El tipo más básico de obstáculo
      hasRot = true;
      hasSkill = false;
      rotSpeed = fallSpeed;
  }
}
```

And finally these two classes are the two types of obstacles that I have.

**So how can I make visible these fields of the specific type of obstacle in the inspector?**

**The problem is that i obtain this visualization with the fields of the father class only.**
[image]

Comment: Try adding this property to the father object: public float ChildFallSpeed
        {
            get
            {
                return this.obstacle.fallSpeed;
            }
            set
            {
                this.obstacle.fallSpeed = value;
            }
        }

Comment: Please make sure to use the correct tags. Your code is in `c#` ... `unityscript` is/was a JavaScript flavor like custom language previously used by Unity and is long deprecated by now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally managed to find a pretty good solution to the problem, and the only complex thing is the fact that you have to learn how to use the editor and view the documentation.

Using serialized properties we can explicitly assign any type of data.
In this case what I wanted was to assign my classes of the types of obstacles to show them on the screen along with all their public variables to make my work easier.

Basically the procedure is the following, first we define a serialized object to which we assign the class that contains the information we want to use in the editor in my case the classes already mentioned.
Then with that object we can search any type of data and assign it explicitly to a serialized property.

Then it is a matter of displaying it on the screen and in my case I change the instance of the property according to an enum so that the updated screen is shown according to the type of obstacle.

**Here I leave the resulting script with the procedure to use this in the editor.**

```
public class ObstacleMaker : MonoBehaviour
{
   public enum ObstacleType { Box, BoxElastic, BoxNinja, BoxTornado, BoxElectro };
   public ObstacleType type;

   public Obstacle obstacle = new Obstacle();

   public Box box = new Box();

   public BoxElastic boxElastic = new BoxElastic();
}
```

**This is the class that contains the types of obstacles instantiated, ready to use in the editor.**

```
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(ObstacleMaker)), CanEditMultipleObjects]
public class ObstacleDefiner : Editor
{
   ObstacleMaker obstacleScript;
   SerializedObject GetTarget;

   #region TYPE OF OBSTACLES
   SerializedProperty Box;
   SerializedProperty BoxElastic;
   SerializedProperty ObstacleInstance;
   #endregion

   private void OnEnable()
   {
       obstacleScript = (ObstacleMaker)target;

       GetTarget = new SerializedObject(obstacleScript);

       #region TIPOS DE OBSTACULOS
       Box = GetTarget.FindProperty("box");
       BoxElastic = GetTarget.FindProperty("boxElastic");
       ObstacleInstance = GetTarget.FindProperty("obstacle");
       #endregion
   }

   public override void OnInspectorGUI()
   {
       //Update our list
       GetTarget.Update();

       using (new EditorGUILayout.VerticalScope("HelpBox"))
       {
           obstacleScript.type = 
           (ObstacleMaker.ObstacleType)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup("Obstacle Type", 
           obstacleScript.type);

           if(GUILayout.Button("Set Obstacle"))
           {
               obstacleScript.SetObstacle();
           }

           EditorGUILayout.Space();

           switch (obstacleScript.type)
           {
               case ObstacleMaker.ObstacleType.Box:
                   EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(Box);
                   break;
               case ObstacleMaker.ObstacleType.BoxElastic:
                   EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(BoxElastic);
                   break;
               default:
                   EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(ObstacleInstance);
                   break;
           }
      }
  }
```

**And this is the class which use the editor to show the classes that I wanted.**

Comment: Nice - and yep it's possible to write editor scripts to show custom things in the Unity editor, sorry for failing to mention that. Just meant literally that didn't see a way to make the default builtin inspector to get to do that for you, due to how C# works.

Comment: It's okay, the important thing is that it's already solved.
What you were absolutely right about and helped me find a better solution, was that I couldn't make the obstacle class become the classes that inherited it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, not in a clear simple way anyhow. You declare this in the ObstacleDefiner which is the script / component that you see in inspector:

```
public Obstacle obstacleDefine;
```

So the inspector shows what Obstacle has. Nothing can change that after the code has been compiled.

I think it's a bad idea to use subclasses for such things anyway. You could do what Unity itself does, and embrace composition instead of inheritance, aggregate the parts you need.

So you could just create Box and (maybe as a subclass of shape if you have many) and Rotation as their own classes, and add those as additional script components to your objects as necessary.

Same way as Unity itself has separate Transform, Mesh renderer, Mesh filter, Rigidbody etc components.

Comment: I thought about using composition instead of inheritance but in this case inheritance seemed better, mainly because it didn't have any function that they shared but it had to be different between the different types of obstacles, so with the overload and common functions it was just what I was looking for.